# ng-hide cause layout to break

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I found `ng-hide` act like display:none which may break my layout, is there any way to make ng-like perform like visibility so it preserve the elements' placement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngHide` uses a predefined class that moves the element by changing its position.

You can simply override the class `.ng-hide` to whatever you want. Add an `.ng-hide` class in another CSS with `!important` flags and it should work. Alternatively, you can use ng-class the same way, with a class of your choosing.

So instead of

```
<div ng-hide="myValue"></div>
```

We will have

```
<div ng-class="{myClass:myValue}"></div>
```

Where `myClass` is however you want to hide your element. For example:

```
.myClass
{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: your ng-class expression correct? I think it should be ng-class="{'class':value}">

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can use  [ng-switch.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)  It conditionally applies DOM templates based on scope expression.